# How to select same objects in two arrays using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I have two arrays of objects. I want select same objects from both arrays and show it. For instance I have following UL ([You can see it at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/concypt/StPew/6/)):

```
<ul>
<li id="one" class="color pro">one</li>
<li id="two" class="color pro">two</li>
<li id="three" class="color">three</li>
<li id="four" class="color">four</li>
</ul>
```

I am using following script to show same objects.

```
var activeElementsColors = $("ul li.color");
var activeElementsPro = $("ul li.pro");                             

var activeElements = activeElementsPro.filter(function(el) {  
return $.inArray(el, activeElementsColors) > -1;
});

activeElements.show();
```

I know I can use $("li.color.pro").show() but above one is just an example. real code is complex than this.

Comment: The `$("ul li.color")` will already give you both sets combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var activeElementsColors = $("ul li.color");
var activeElementsPro = $("ul li.pro");                             

var activeElements = activeElementsPro.filter(function(el,e) {  

    return $.inArray(e, activeElementsColors) > -1;
});
console.log(activeElements);
activeElements.show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/StPew/8/

Comment: I am wondering which one is more efficient. Your's or pimvdb's? btw both works fine for me ;)

Comment: also if I have more groups like for example: activeElementsColors, 
activeElementsPro, activeElementsType, activeElementsSize etc?

Comment: I don't have the jQuery sources (and I doubt I'd be able to read them), but I suspect pimvdb's is more efficient really, because it skips a dereferencing that you usually woudn't program naively with an overload in an API. Profile it dpoing it a thousand times, get back with some numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument in the function passed to `.filter` is the index of the element in the jQuery object, not the element itself. Use `this` instead, which does refer to the element: http://jsfiddle.net/StPew/7/.

```
var activeElements = activeElementsPro.filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(this, activeElementsColors) > -1;
});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> `function(`**`index`**`)`
>
> A function used as a test for each element in the set. **`this`** is the current DOM element.

Comment: I am wondering which one is more efficient. Your's or 3nigma's? btw both works fine for me ;)

Comment: i'll leave the explanation to @pimvdb `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to the `filter` callback is the index of the current element. Use `this` instead.

```
return $.inArray(this, activeElementsColors) > -1;
```

That said what you doing seems seriously wrong. Assuming what you actually want is intersection of `.pro` and `.color` selectors, then you can simply do

```
$(".pro:.color").show();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/StPew/9/)

Answer (score 1):

`.filter()` takes a jQuery object as a parameter and returns a new object that consists of the elements in the first object minus the ones that aren't in the second jQuery object, so if you already have the jQuery objects, you can use them like this to show the objects that are in both:

```
var activeElementsColors = $("ul li.color");
var activeElementsPro = $("ul li.pro"); 
activeElementsPro.filter(activeElementsColors).show();
```